# How to perform a vectorized function on a 2D numpy array?

Tags: python

```
vecs = np.array([[1, 2, 3],
                 [4, 5, 6],
                 [7, 8, 9]])

def find_len(vector):
    return (vector[0] ** 2 + vector[1] ** 2 + vector[2] ** 2) ** 0.5

vec_len = np.vectorize(find_len)
```

I want to apply find_len to every vector in the 2d array and create a new numpy array with the values returned. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
res= []
for i in range(vecs.shape[0]):
    res.append(find_len(vecs[i]))
res=np.array(res)
```

results in

```
array([ 3.74165739,  8.77496439, 13.92838828])
```

you can also make this in one line:

```
res = np.array([find_len(x) for x in vecs[range(vecs.shape[0])]])
```

Comment: Is it possible to implement this without using a loop (bc it might slow down the code)? Thanks!

Comment: I dont't know. The solution from @Kraigolas is way faster.

(vecs**2).sum(axis=1)**0.5   ---> 1µs

my solution:
res = np.array([find_len(x) for x in vecs[range(vecs.shape[0])]])   ---> 5ms

so if you need speed, better use the other solution

Answer (score 1):

Are you just looking for this result:

```
array([ 3.74165739,  8.77496439, 13.92838828])
```

because you can achieve that without `vectorize`, just use:

```
(vecs**2).sum(axis=1)**0.5
```

This also has the advantage of not being specific to vectors of length 3.

---

Operations are already applied element-wise, so you can handle the squaring and square rooting normally. `sum(axis=1)` says to sum along the rows.

Comment: Thank you! I also need to implement other functions like find_len to the vectors though, so it would be greatly appreciated if there's a way to do that without using loops.

Comment: @NewToPython This answer doesn't involve loops.